# How to keep local changes after reloading webpage

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, local, reload, devtools

I just want to change some thumbnails on youtube videos for a joke, but when I change the thumbnails src to another image, I just get the small image not found box.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube retrieves their videos dynamically in a script. It retrieves the thumbnails from https://i.ytimg.com/*. My guess is that you can try to upload a youtube video with the thumbnail of your target, and use the image src of your uploaded video. But whenever you resize the display dimension or reload more videos on to your homepage, the thumbnails will revert back.